# Android selector adding weird padding

Tags: android, android-drawable

Here is my simple background selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/filters_group_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/filters_group_pressed" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/filters_group"/>

</selector>
```

In the layout editor layout look's like: [image]

After launching on nexus 7 (first generation) it look's like: [image]

It looks fine if I set as background my 9patch graphic (which selector contains) and not the selector. It looks like an android bug to me...

White bar should be stretched at whole width and the icon should be centered. Here is the layout:

```
<org.mycustomview.MyCustomLinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/group_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/filter_group_button_selector"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_table" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sala 1"
        android:lines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</org.mycustomview.MyCustomLinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your layout XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be a bug. It added right padding itself. I added android:`paddingRight="0dp"` to my `MyCustomLinearLayout` and it's work like expected.

Comment: If your problem solved by this then you should close this question by accepting your own answer.

Comment: Which I can do in 2 days from now.